# Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js` from ``:

Tags: react-native

Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js` from ``:

None of these files exist:

```
 * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.cff11639.js/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at /Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:841:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (/Users/silent/Documents/CompanyTest/ConnectPlus/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also have the same issue, the issue is because we use chrome debugger.
When I go through https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging we have to install the 'react-devtools' package. After some time browsing internet. I found that its difficult to use chrome desbugger. So I stop the debug and clear the cahce

> npx react-native start --reset-cache

after that I restart back the apps. And the error gone.

Comment: I did use react-devtools in the past, but after upgrading to RN 0.62.2, when I select 'debug' from the react-native menu, clicking buttons in my app doesn't do anything. Have you encountered such a problem (buttons resume working when I disable debug)

Comment: I not sure about this

Answer (score 2):

Stop debugging from the simulator. Hard reload debugger tab in chrome by `alt + control + click on reload button` and choose `Empty cache and hard reload` then restart the debugger from simulator.

Comment: This is the correct answer. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28844

I actually didn't need to empty the cache, just close the old debugger tab.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for a couple days as well. I went to my terminal and ran `adb shell "date" && date`, and realized that the time between my 2 devices (tablet and laptop) were off by a few seconds. I restarted my tablet and laptop, ensured that the times were back in sync with the above command, and everything is running smoothly now.

Apparently this has to do with button presses in react-native depending on the device's time.